# Transfer text from tab to tab using wx.flatnotebook

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I have a flatnotebook with two pages. I would like to have the text entered in the Text Ctrl on page 1 displayed in the text ctrl on page 2 on a button press. When I add 'self.secondTab = SecondTab(self)', I get another text box superimposed on page 1 and the text transfers to that box on button press.There is something small that I'm missing, please help.

```
import wx
import wx.lib.agw.flatnotebook as fnb

class FirstTab(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, -1)

        self.secondTab = SecondTab(self)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.txtOne = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)
        self.btnOne = wx.Button(self, -1, "Transfer text to Tab 2")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.sendText, self.btnOne)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.txtOne, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        sizer.Add(self.btnOne, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    def sendText(self, event):
        text = self.txtOne.GetValue()
        self.secondTab.txtTwo.WriteText(text)

class SecondTab(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):

        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, -1)

        self.parent = parent
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.txtTwo = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.txtTwo, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1,"Notebook", size=(300,300))

        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        notebook = wx.Notebook(panel)

        page1 = FirstTab(notebook)
        page2 = SecondTab(notebook)

        notebook.AddPage(page1, "Tab 1")
        notebook.AddPage(page2, "Tab 2")

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        sizer.Add(notebook, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Layout()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = Frame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I am not a Python programmer but it seems to me that your `def sendText(self, event):` event should be defined in your `class Frame`

Answer (score 0):

When you call

```
self.secondTab = SecondTab(self)
```

you are constructing another instance of the SecondTab class.  You do not want to do that, you want to reference the instance you constructed in Frame.

```
global frame  #reference frame constructed in main
frame.page1.txtTwo.WriteText(text)
```

Of course, you need to make frame global, so you can modify it.

Comment: You give me too much credit. I couldn't figure out how to reference tab2's textCtrl from tab1. I am at a loss on how to make the frame global. There are many  confusing posts on this subject. If I add frame =Frame(), I get 'RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded'. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, I overcame this hurdle by using pubsub. I followed Mike Driscoll's example from his [blog](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/09/05/wxpython-2-9-and-the-newer-pubsub-api-a-simple-tutorial/)

```
import wx
from wx.lib.pubsub import pub

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1,"Notebook", size=(300,300))

        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        notebook = wx.Notebook(panel)

        page1 = FirstTab(notebook)
        page2 = SecondTab(notebook)

        notebook.AddPage(page1, "Tab 1")
        notebook.AddPage(page2, "Tab 2")

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        sizer.Add(notebook, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Layout()


class FirstTab(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, -1)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.txtOne = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)
        self.btnOne = wx.Button(self, -1, "Transfer text to Tab 2")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.sendText, self.btnOne)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.txtOne, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        sizer.Add(self.btnOne, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    def sendText(self, event):
        text = self.txtOne.GetValue()
        pub.sendMessage("panelListener", message = text)

class SecondTab(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, -1)
        pub.subscribe(self.myListener, "panelListener")

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.txtTwo = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.txtTwo, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    def myListener(self, message):
        self.txtTwo.WriteText(message)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = Frame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```